# How could I deploy a website to the Internet with Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll

I have made a website I really like, but I don't know how to deploy it. I've heard about Jekyll, but anything will work for me. If you have any advice, please share!    :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most popular and probably easiest way is to use GitHub Pages. Github Pages has built-in Jekyll support and will automatically build your site and serve it to a github.io domain or a custom domain if you set it up.

Jekyll Docs: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/github-pages/

GitHub Pages Docs: https://docs.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll

I recently learned about Netlify, which purports to do the same thing as GitHub Pages with some additional features. It has a free tier, and they have a published guide on deploying Jekyll sites: https://www.netlify.com/blog/2020/04/02/a-step-by-step-guide-jekyll-4.0-on-netlify/

Comment: Wow, thank you so much!